# Is there an example for a limited set that is not measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I asked myself whether there is an example for a subset  $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with the property that it is limited but not Lebesgue-measurbale? Do you have a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that by "limited" you mean "bounded," note that [Vitali sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set) - the usual first example of a non-measurable set - are nonmeasurable subsets of $[0,1]$ ...

---

On the other hand, there are some known restrictions on what a non-measurable set could possibly be. For example:

- Every set of [outer measure $0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_set) is measurable.

  - Indeed, it turns out that a set $X$ is measurable if and only if there is some [$G_\delta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%CE%B4_set) set $Y$ such that the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) $X\triangle Y$ has measure zero; this follows from the [regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularity_theorem_for_Lebesgue_measure) of Lebesgue measure.
- Every [Borel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set) set is measurable.

  - In fact, this can be pushed further: every [analytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_set) set is measurable. Under [further set-theoretic hypotheses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_cardinal) we can extend this to even broader collections of sets - e.g. under appropriate large cardinal hypotheses, every [projective set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_hierarchy) is measurable. This sort of thing is one of the topics studied in [**descriptive set theory**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptive_set_theory), with a main theme being that - especially under large cardinal hypotheses - "reasonably definable" sets of real numbers are tame in various senses (including measurability).

Comment: Thank you all for you asnwers, they we're a great help to me.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose otherwise. Then **every** set $S$ of real numbers would be measurable, because$$S=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb Z}\bigl(S\cap[n,n+1)\bigr)$$and each set $\bigl(S\cap[n,n+1)\bigr)$ is bounded.